Why does path.contains(point) return seemingly inconsistent results? What am I missing?

My goal is to check if a point is inside a region. The code below illustrates a sample with the region defined with an Envelope struct.
Sample points along the border, inside and outside of the region are also defined.
all is then depicted using "Chart"
To check if the point is inside or not, I construct a Path from the "Envelope" points and than check if this path.contains(the point).
Some points that are on the border are found to be outside, while others are inside. What am I missing here? Any ideas?
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Envelope:Identifiable {
    let id=UUID()
    var x:Double
    var y:Double
}

struct Point:Identifiable {
    let id=UUID()
    let point:CGPoint
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let envelope:[Envelope]=[Envelope(x: 1.0, y: 1.0),
                             Envelope(x: 1.0, y: 2.0),
                             Envelope(x: 2.0, y: 2.0),
                             Envelope(x: 2.0, y: 1.0),
                             Envelope(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    ]
    
    
    let pointToCheck1=CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    let pointToCheck2=CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
    let pointToCheck3=CGPoint(x: 2.0, y: 2.0)
    let pointToCheck4=CGPoint(x: 2.0, y: 1.0)
    let pointToCheck5=CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    let pointToCheck6=CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 1.0)
    let pointToCheck7=CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.5)
    let pointToCheck8=CGPoint(x: 2.0, y: 1.5)
    let pointToCheck9=CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 2.0)
    let pointToCheck10=CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 2.1)
    
    
    
    var points:[Point] {
        [Point(point: pointToCheck1),
         Point(point: pointToCheck2),
         Point(point: pointToCheck3),
         Point(point: pointToCheck4),
         Point(point: pointToCheck5),
         Point(point: pointToCheck6),
         Point(point: pointToCheck7),
         Point(point: pointToCheck8),
         Point(point: pointToCheck9),
         Point(point: pointToCheck10)]
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(envelope) { item in
                    LineMark (x: .value("", item.x),
                              y: .value("", item.y)
                    ).lineStyle(by: .value("", "CG Limit"))
                }
                
                ForEach(points) { point in
                    PointMark (x: .value("", Double(point.point.x)),
                               y: .value("", Double(point.point.y)))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.orange)
                    .annotation {
                        Text("\(checkIntersection(point.point)) \(point.point)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .chartXScale(domain: [0.7, 2.3])
            .chartYScale(domain: [0.7, 2.3])
            
            
            
        }
    }
    
    private func checkIntersection(_ point:CGPoint)->String {
        var toReturn="Outside"
        
        var pathObject=Path()
        var isFirst=true
        for sort in envelope {
            let cgPoint=CGPoint(x: sort.x, y: sort.y)
            if isFirst {
                pathObject.move(to: cgPoint)
                isFirst=false
            }else{
                pathObject.addLine(to: cgPoint)
            }
        }
        
        if pathObject.contains(point) {
            toReturn="Inside"
        }
        
        return toReturn
    }
    
    
}


Looks consistent to me, all of the points on the edge of the region that are reporting as inside are towards the origin. Might not be intended, but I don't think it's inconsistent.

What do you mean by "towards the origin"? I was hoping that the contains would simply return true/false if the point being checked was inside or on the border of that region. so I was expecting all points on the border to be "inside", not only some of them. thx for clerification Nick. Is there any "function" that I could use to return intended result?

The definition of "inside" is up to debate. I myself would expect all points on the border to be outside. When something is totally inside it's clearly inside, and when something is totally outside, it's outside. But when something is on the edge of inside and outside, it's less clear. It's like trying to classify 0 as greater than 0 or less than 0 (a point left of a line or right of a line, when it sits on the line). This is up to the implementer, and in this case, you get the functionality you observe. I don't actually know a solution, just pointing out where the inconsistency comes from.

Yes, you are right, I understand your point with the "inside/outside". I was seeing only math behind. So as all points on the border would have a "crossing" with the region, I would consider them inside. By the way, I probably found a solution. Rather then using Path(), I tried UIBezierPath() which seem to return what I need.

I may have found a solution. Instead of using Path(), I tried UIBezierPath() which returns my expected result.
private func checkIntersection(_ point:CGPoint)->String {
        var toReturn="Outside"
        
        var pathObject=UIBezierPath()
        var isFirst=true
        for sort in envelope {
            let cgPoint=CGPoint(x: sort.x, y: sort.y)
            if isFirst {
                pathObject.move(to: cgPoint)
                isFirst=false
            }else{
                pathObject.addLine(to: cgPoint)
            }
        }
        if pathObject.contains(point) {
            toReturn="Inside"
        }
        
        return toReturn
    }

